# FFMPEG command line execution in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I'm a newbie in android programming and this is kind of abstract, I don't know much about ndk but there are a lot of ffmpeg libraries with java wrappers for direct usage if I'm right. I can import them to my project but have no idea as to how to use them to execute ffmpeg commands through them. Could you please suggest me any particular library and how could I use them to get ffmpeg commands executed?

Answer (score 3):

There's a pretty straight forward library that wraps FFmpeg for Android called [JavaCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv)

To compile it with your Android project, just add the following lines to your .gradle file:

```
compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '1.0'
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '2.7.1-1.0', classifier: 'android-arm'
```

Then you can use the ffmpeg methods directly from your code. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks, I don't need to download those files separately to include them in my project, do I? Also, my problem is that I have no idea on how to execute commands such as `ffmpeg -i source_video.avi -b 300 -s 320x240 -vcodec xvid -ab 32 -ar 24000 -acodec aac final_video.mp4` using them. That's where I got stuck actually.

Comment: No, all you need will be automatically downloaded. I'm not really sure about that specific command, but the library contains several examples on how to record video. This ones for instance might help https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/samples/RecordActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried these libraries?

[guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java)

[appunite/AndroidFFmpeg](https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg)

Comment: Hey, thanks and yes I've tried importing them but then again, I have no idea on how to execute commands such as `ffmpeg -i source_video.avi -b 300 -s 320x240 -vcodec xvid -ab 32 -ar 24000 -acodec aac final_video.mp4` using them. That's where I got stuck actually.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this link. It may help
http://androidwarzone.blogspot.in/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html

Comment: I looked into it but unfortunately ffmpeg4android should be purchased for usage other than personal usage. Hence I can't go with that.